# UTF troubleshooting: inequality signs: ≠,╘

Tags: unicode, utf

Alt+2260 = `╘` = U+2260

Does `≠` equal `╘` ? Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: ╘ is [U+2558](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2558/index.htm), not U+2260. And this absolutely not related to programming

Comment: U+2558 types the following symbol: ■

Comment: you're mistaking between Unicode code point (U+XXXX) and Alt code (Alt+XXXX). They're completely different things. Typing Alt+2558/Alt+254 will input the character at code point 254 which is ■ in CP437 since 2558 % 256 = 254 just like what I answered

Comment: Works. Thank you. Now, while pressing Alt key and typing +,2,2,6,0  on the NumPad, after releasing the Alt key the result is: ≠

Comment: If this issue is absolutely not related to programming, where do you think it does belong and does related to? how would you tag and categorize it?

Comment: it should be on https://superuser.com/. I've already voted to close and move to there. Anyway if my answer helps can you [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

The number is treated as decimal modulo 256. 2260 % 256 = 212, and `╘` is code point 212 in code page 437

You need to use the hex numpad instead of the normal Alt code

---

Windows disables hex-numpad by default due to backward compatibility issues. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Num</kbd> produces the corresponding character in [ANSI or OEM code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) only and **won't work for code points larger than 255**.

A few apps do support larger values but treat them as decimal just like how [Alt codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) were always treated, which means <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2260</kbd> will produce [U+08D4](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0008D4/index.htm) (0x08D4 = 2260) and not U+2260. Some other apps just take the first or last 3 digits. But by default in almost all applications if you input any large values then **only the low byte of the real value is taken as the code point**, i.e. modulo 256

So pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2260</kbd> will be equivalent to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>212</kbd> because 2260 % 256 = 212. When you run US Windows which uses [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) for the OEM code page then at code point 212 is [╘ (U+2258)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2558/index.htm) which is what you saw

To produce ≠ (U+2260) you need to use the hex numpad by creating a registry key named `EnableHexNumpad` with type `REG_SZ` in `HKCU\Control Panel\Input Method`, set its value to 1 then reboot. After that you can type the character as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Unicode value</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+2260</kbd> in your case). The <kbd>+</kbd> after <kbd>Alt</kbd> is really important to differentiate between decimal ANSI/OEM code points and Unicode code points. If you use other applications like MS Word then there are other better ways to insert Unicode characters

For more information read

- [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm)
- [Insert Unicode characters via the keyboard?](https://superuser.com/q/47420/241386)
- [Insert ASCII or Unicode Latin-based symbols and characters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0?ocmsassetID=HA010167539&CorrelationId=1ed32bc2-69ca-4bed-b751-4260640e7d09&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)