# alt+8377(numeric keyboard) types ╣ instead of ₹ which it should according to alt code shown online?

Tags: unicode, ascii

Typing <kbd>Alt+8377</kbd> types `╣` instead of `₹`, which it should type according to literature online. Moreover, the ASCII/Alt code of `╣` is <kbd>Alt+185</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt+185</kbd> also types `╣`.

Can someone explain why this is, and how to type `₹` with <kbd>Alt</kbd> codes?

Comment: Where to? In a text editor or on the command line? It's possible that wherever you are typing this only has limited charset support (Windows `cmd.exe`, i.e. the Windows command line, is a classical offender for this).

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming and already has tons of duplicates: [Why are my Alt codes different from what is generally reported online?](https://superuser.com/q/1451575/241386), [Alt code troubleshooting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57742453/995714), [Unicode arrows with Altcode](https://superuser.com/q/815976/241386)... TL;DR: [You're using the wrong code page](https://superuser.com/a/1666633/241386) and Alt+8377 almost never works outside MS Word or a few word processing apps. Just use Unicode instead and type Alt+`+20B9` after enabling hex numpad

Answer (score 2):

The ALT keycodes only give the OEM or Windows code page characters, not Unicode code points (8377 is the decimal Unicode codepoint for ₹), of which there are only 256 characters per code page.  8377 modulo 256 is 185 which is why you get the symbol you see.  ALT 185 gives the [OEM codepage (cp437 on US Windows)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) character (╣), ALT 0185 gives the  [Windows codepage (cp1252 on US Windows)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character (¹).  See https://www.alt-codes.net/.

You can't type arbitrary Unicode codepoints with ALT codes.  Use the `Character Map` utility that comes with Windows to look up Unicode characters, or for a particular language you can install IME (input method editor) support for that language via Language Settings.